Vite + React + TS error TS2307: Cannot find module 'shared/api/request.ts' or its corresponding type declarations
When running jest test:

src/shared/api/request.test.ts:1:24 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'shared/api/request.ts' or its corresponding type declarations.
1 import { getUrl } from 'shared/api/request.ts';

My files look like:
tsconfig.app.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "Bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "moduleDetection": "force",
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noUncheckedSideEffectImports": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "src/*": ["./src/*"],
      "shared/*": ["./src/shared/*"],
      "entities/*": ["./src/entities/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src", "./jest.setup.ts"]
}

jest.config.js
import { pathsToModuleNameMapper } from 'ts-jest';
import tsConfig from './tsconfig.app.json' with { type: "json" };

console.log(pathsToModuleNameMapper(tsConfig.compilerOptions.paths))

/**@type {import('ts-jest').JestConfigWithTsJest} */
export default {
  testEnvironment: "jsdom",
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest",
  },
  roots: ['<rootDir>'],
  modulePaths: [tsConfig.compilerOptions.baseUrl],
  moduleNameMapper: pathsToModuleNameMapper(
    tsConfig.compilerOptions.paths),
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.ts'],
};


jest --show-config
      "moduleNameMapper": [
        [
          "^src/(.*)$",
          "./src/$1"
        ],
        [
          "^shared/(.*)$",
          "./src/shared/$1"
        ],
        [
          "^entities/(.*)$",
          "./src/entities/$1"
        ]
      ],

How can I resolve this error?
I expect to fix my routes in runtime

I approved your question so it appears publicly on the website. Now you can add your solution as a self-answer below so others with the same error can benefit from it :)
